# JavaScript not displaying (PHP)

Tags: javascript, php

I think there is a problem with my JavaScript. It's basically not working, no matter anything i try.

I have this VERY simple script:

```
<div id="simplediv" style="background-color:yellow;border:1px solid black;display:none;width:200px;height:200px;">Click anywhere in the document to auto-close me</div>

<a href="#" onclick="Popup.show('simplediv');return false;">Click Here</a>
```

And on this website it works:
http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/lib/popup/example.php

But when i add it to my own page:

```
<head>
<title>Script</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="simplediv" style="background-color:yellow;border:1px solid black;display:none;width:200px;height:200px;">Click anywhere in the document to auto-close me</div>

<a href="#" onclick="Popup.show('simplediv');return false;">Click Here To Show DIV</a>
</body>
```

It won't work. i've also tried with other javascript codes inside the  tags, and they all worked exactly on the website where I took it from, and I don't know why it doesn't work now.

Does anyone know why it's behaving like this?

Comment: `Popup.show('#simplediv')`, perhaps? And are you sure the popup library actually got loaded? Check your javascript console for errors.

Comment: besides comment above, I dont see js inclusion (a code for Popup class)

Comment: @MarcB yes! On my console it says "Uncaught ReferenceError: Popup is not defined"
What should i do now?

Comment: So load up the popup library. e.g. `<script src="yourlibraryfile.js"></script>`

Comment: @MarcB I guess I don't have the library... are you sure I need it? Because in the tutorial it just tells me to add the little piece of code...

Comment: yes, because they're assuming you've loaded the library into your page. `Popup` is not something that's built into Javascript.

Comment: This popup stuff is only supported by IE. I guess they were using a workaround on their on website

Comment: This is the URL of the popup library http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/libsource.php/popup/combined/popup.js (taken from the site you linked to). I suggest you look for a newer popup plugin though as this "Toolbox" hasn't been updated in almost 5 years

Comment: Thanks @koala_dev, yes I have found the js now and resolved the problem. This popup is really useful, and now that it works i will start to customize it!

Answer (score 0):

As stated, the onclick="" Popup function is not defined; your browser doesn't know what this function is supposed to do.

Edit as you need, but putting something like this in your header would define your function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showDiv(div_id){
   document.getElementById(div_id).style.visibility="visible";
}

function hideDiv(div_id){
   document.getElementById(div_id).style.visibility="hidden";
}
</script>
```

Then you would call these functions in your onclick="" event with the needed parameters. Similar to the following:

```
<a href="#" onclick="hideDiv('simplediv');">Click Here To Hide DIV</a>

<a href="#" onclick="showDiv('simplediv');">Click Here To Show DIV</a>
```